# Is there a name for "small ideas you get at a time or place least expected"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Small ideas, a flash of wit you get
1) when you're doing everyday routines; and
2) when you don't expect fresh ideas to come to you; and
3) when you're not trying to find fresh ideas.

For example: This morning, I was stuck in the usual traffic jam, mind wandering. Suddenly, I have a(n) _______. I was excited about this ______ throughout the day.

Ideally, this is a one-word name.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Cascabel, I'm looking for something that also applies to less impactful ideas, such as a plot for a new story, the melody of a new song etc. Epiphany seems to be referring to life-changing realizations? Is it suitable in this context?

Comment: Also try _serendipity_.

Comment: @Cascabel yes I should have thought the problem through before I ask! Sorry about that. Now I get a better idea of what I'm looking for. I'm editing the question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could it be a *brainwave*?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single word, generally this would be conveyed in phrases such as 'being struck by an idea/notion/thought', 'having a lightbulb moment', 'a thought came out of nowhere', 'an idea popped into my head', 'I had a flash of inspiration', 'in a blinding flash the plot came to me..'...

Answer (score 1):

Dutch and German have a word for this: *ingeving* resp. *Eingebung*, but it seems to have no equivalent in English. The closest I can get is *spontaneous inspiration*; inspiration usually happens over a longer period so you need another word to indicate that it's only a brief moment. The Dutch and German words have this connotation built in, but 'ingiving' isn't a word.

Answer (score 0):

Epiphany ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany))

> 1. a usually sudden manifestation or perception of the essential nature or meaning of something
> 2. an intuitive grasp of reality through something (as an event) usually simple and striking
> 3. an illuminating discovery, realization, or disclosure